# Aquiring larger friends image from pacebook graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

while

```
http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture
```

gives me the given ID profile image at 50*50 size
and
    http://graph.facebook.com/$id/picture?type=large

gives me the given ID profile image at 200*200 size

I'm a bit struggling with the friends.

```
HTTP://graph.facebook.com/$id?fields=friends{picture}
```

gives me all the profile pics of the user friends in 1 call, but 50*50
I did not find the right syntax to retrieve all the friend's image at 200*200 size (?type=large) in 1 batch

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends

And while I can send an individual request for each friend, I'd like to try doing it in 1 call for performance reasons.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

```
id?fields=friends{picture.type(large)}
```

or

```
id/friends?fields=picture.type(large)
```

See “Field Expansion”, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion